# Windows Phone 7 emulator : Can I simulate a phone call

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation

I am looking into developing for Windows Phone 7. For testing my app, I need to be able to simulate a phone call. Is it possible in the emulator ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. it's not possible to simualte your application being interupted by a phone call being received. It's also been announced that as [the RTM emulator will only support MinUI](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Inside+Windows+Phone/Inside-Windows-Phone-02-The-beta-release-and-the-roadmap-to-RTM/) there will not be a way to test this in the emulator for the foreseeable future. You will need to test this on a real device.

Unfortunately there is no way round testing this on a real device as other forms of interuption, such as returning to the start screen or performing a search (both courtesy of the hardware buttons onthe front of the device), have a different impact on the running application.

Comment: @intoOrbit "MinUI" is the name/term for the amount of the Operating system that is available in the emulator. Short for "Minimal User Interface". The emulator only includes IE, access to some device settings, any apps you install and the functionality required for your apps to interact with the OS--but not with Hubs.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can emulate the phone call itself, but you *can* emulate launching the dialler with a number and an optional name.

For unit testing purposes, you'll probably want to create an interface with the appropriate functionality, and then a wrapper around the system `PhoneCallTask` type.

As the `PhoneCallTask` doesn't actually make the call directly - it just opens up the UI allowing the user to connect conveniently - you can test that functionality in the emulator nice and easily. Mind you, if you *do* then hit "call" you get to see the phone UI, and see the "phone call in progress" icon at the top. The network reports itself as "Fake GSM Network".

Comment: This is also how I've tested running up a phonecall during my app's execution. It works in the emu.

Comment: @Jon: Is there an example that shows how to test this? Or do you have to code this into your app?