# How to simulate an incoming call within the windows phone simulator?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I need to test how my app reacts when an incoming call interrupts execution.  How can I do this in the simulator?

Comment: do you want to make call from your app to emulator ?

Comment: @user3683136, I am using my app xxx, at the time i am receiving some call. How to Test this scenario?

Comment: Do you want to test your App in a Tombstoned state?

Comment: @yogesh , Yes, that is also fine..

Answer (score 1):

[image: Screenshot attached]Go to Properties of your App(right click on solution Explorer), Select Debug tab  and there you will find a checkbox(Tombstone upon deactivation while debugging), check that. After checking it whenever the apps gets deactivated , it will get in to tombstone state while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Scenario is **not possible** to Test in **Emulator**. You can make call from your app in emulator but Receiving can be tested in only **Device**. for more Reference you can refer this Question [Windows Phone 7 emulator : Can I simulate a phone call.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653654/windows-phone-7-emulator-can-i-simulate-a-phone-call)

To test for making a call from your app, you can find Reference here [How to use the phone call task for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394025(v=vs.105).aspx)